# Programación en python

Tags: python

Tengo el siguiente código y quisiera saber ¿Cómo detectar si el usuario ingresa un número fuera del rango de 0 a 1024? y por otra parte ¿Cómo detectar si el usuario ingresa un número con decimales?

CÓDIGO:

```
x = int(input("Ingrese un número entre 0 y 1024 \n"))
a = 0
b = 1024
test = True
if x == 0:
    print("1. Tu número es 0, gracias por jugar")
    test = False
else:
    if x == 1024:
        print("2. Tu número es 1024, gracias por jugar")
        test = False
    while test == True:
        n = int((a+b)/2)
        if n == x:
            print("3. Tu número es " + str(n) + ", gracias por jugar")
            break
        else:
            if n < x:
                a = n
            else: b = n
```

Answer (score 1):

### Rango

Para detectar si un número está en un rango python permite emplear la misma sintaxis que en matemáticas `(limite_inferior <= número_de_interés <= limite_superior)`

```
x = 3
li, ls = 1, 20
print(li <= x <= ls)
# True
```

## Decimal

Para saber si un número posee parte decimal se puede usar un pequeño truco.
Todo número por definición es divisible por `1` entonces el resto será cero para cualquier número entero.
En python existe un operador `%` que al emplearlo da el resto entre dos números a dividir, por ejemplo `5 % 3` su resto es `2`

Entonces si el numero es decimal el resto siempre será mayor a cero si el denominador es `1`:

```
for i in range(10):
  i*=0.5
  print(i,":",i%1)

# 0.0 : 0.0 <-cero cuando el numerador es entero (0)
# 0.5 : 0.5
# 1.0 : 0.0 <-cero cuando el numerador es entero (1)
# 1.5 : 0.5
# 2.0 : 0.0 <-cero cuando el numerador es entero (2)
# 2.5 : 0.5
# 3.0 : 0.0 <-cero cuando el numerador es entero (3)
# 3.5 : 0.5
# 4.0 : 0.0 <-cero cuando el numerador es entero (4)
# 4.5 : 0.5
```

## Código

Con lo anterior se puede tener un código tentativo para lo que estás preguntado (en el input se reemplazó `int` por `float` para el caso del decimal)

```
x = float(input("Ingrese un número entre 0 y 1024 \n"))
li, ls = 0, 1024

if (li<=x<=ls) and x%1==0:
  print("Tu numero es: {}".format(x))
else:
  if x%1>0:
    print("Numero {} es decimal".format(x))
  if not li<=x<=ls:
    print("Numero {} fuera del rango [{}, {}]".format(x,li,ls))
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!

Comment: Muy buena la parte de Decimal.

Answer (score 1):

Basado en la forma en como escribiste tu código desarrolle este pequeño control de errores incluyendo un ciclo while para regresar cada vez que se detecta una intrusión.
simplemente es un if siempre que sea un numero diferente a el rango definido por range regresa y para el decimal defini la entrada del dato como int de no ser asi entra en un ciclo de excepciones try except.

```
contador = 0
while(contador == 0):
    try:
        x = int(input("Ingrese un número entre 0 y 1024 \n"))
        if (int(x) != range(0,1024)):
             print("Te encuentras fuera de rango permitido,por favor intenta de nuevo")
             contador = 0
        else:
                contador += 1
                print("ahora si corre tu codigo")
    except:
         print("Este tipo de dato no esta permitido ,ingrese un entero porfavor")
```

Answer (score 0):

Para el primer problema, podrías poner un :

```
if a<0 || b>1024:
print:("Es un numero fuera de rango")
```

Para el segundo, este podria servirte:

```
def lee_entero():
while True:
    entrada = raw_input("Escribe un numero entero: ")
try:
    entrada = int(entrada)
    return entrada
except ValueError:
    print "La entrada es incorrecta: escribe un numero entero"
```

Espero te sirva de ayuda mi respuesta.